# php Using if is not changing?

Tags: php, if-statement

If the `$status` = `pending` or `success` the result is always warning. How is that possible? Am I using the `else` right? Maybe someone can help me with it. The `$status` is coming from a database. Can you explain whats the difference between `=` and `==` ?

Thanks sincerely Dennis

```
<?php if ($status == "pending") { 
            $class ="warning";
      } else if ($status == "succes"){
            $class = "succes";
      }
?>
```

Comment: are you using it in loop ??

Comment: Is this your exact code? The `=` assigns, the `==` compares. Have you outputted `$status` when it is returning `warning` and confirmed it is as expected?

Comment: Your code looks syntactically ok. So, $status probably always contains "pending". Can you _echo $status_ before the _if (...)_ and check this?

Comment: yes its used in a loop. Like for each variable in the database its create a line in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your 2nd Question:
A single = is for asigning a value to a variable.

`variable = "test"`

Double == is for comparing

`1 == 1 // True`

Comment: but do you see something wrong in the code i writed ? because he see the output always as "warning"

Comment: Sorry I cant. It must be something with the db